# Как убрать, надпись None? если нет, подписи к фото?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите, как убрать, надпись `None`, если без подписи к фото, для Телеграм.

Код:

```py
await bot.send_photo(
    1admin_id,
    message.photo[-1].file_id,
    '{0}\n {2}'.format(message.caption, message.chat.id,
                         message.from_user.first_name,
                         message.from_user.last_name,
                         message.from_user.username),
    parse_mode='html')
```

Если без подписи, вместо `None`, надпись `True`

`message.caption is None`

Если без подписи, вместо `None`, надпись `False`

`message.caption is not None`

Так же, за подпись, отмечает этот код: `{0}`

Может, что то, туда прописать, к этому нулю, но не знаю.

Comment: Добавьте проверку, варианты: `message.caption or 'True'` или `message.caption if message.caption else 'True'` или `caption = message.caption` + `if not caption: caption = 'True'`

Comment: не помогло, пишет True, последний, ошибку пишет invalid

Comment: Что вам нужно чтоб писало, если нет подписи?

Comment: @Miki, мне показалось, что вы хотели писать `True` если `message.caption` отсутствует :) Замените тогда в моих примерах `True'` на ту строку, которую вы покажете при отсутствии `message.caption`, можно хоть пустую строку `''`. Либо вручную составляйте строку, например через `+`. Лучше приложите пример строки, которую вы в `bot.send_photo` передаете и какую строку вы хотели бы в итоге получить.

Comment: Чтобы, не писало, None, спрятало эту надпись, а так же, спрятало True и False.
Чтобы пользователь, не Видел None, True, False, если нет подписи, к фото.

Comment: Теперь с подписью, не работает, не публикует, без подписи, все отлично.
message.caption if message.caption else ''

Как исправить?

Comment: Прописал вот так:
message.caption, message.caption else ''

Как к нулю, прописать, однёрку,? прописал так:
{0, 1} 
Но ошибка invalid syntax